# How can I center nodes in a Graphviz cluster

Tags: graphviz, dot

I have the follow dot definition of a graph:

```
digraph G {
bgcolor="gray"

node [
    style=filled
    shape="circle"
    fillcolor="green4"
    penwidth="2"
    color="green1"
    fontcolor="white"
]

root [
   shape="box"
   color="white"
   fontcolor="white"
   label="hello"
]

AAA_1 [
    label="AAA"
]

BBB_2 [
    label="BBB"
]

subgraph cluster_ccc {
    color=gray
    fillcolor="blue"
    style=filled
    label="ccccc"
    labelloc=b
    fontcolor="white"
    labeljust=l

    subgraph cluster_south_a {
        label="aaaaaaaaaaa"

        5 [ label="" fillcolor="red" ]
        6 [ label="" fillcolor="red" ]

        5 -> 6
    }

    subgraph cluster_south_b {
        label="bbbbbbbbbbb"

        7 [ label="" fillcolor="red" ]
        8 [ label="" fillcolor="red" ]

        7 -> 8
    }
}

root -> AAA_1
root -> BBB_2

AAA_1 -> 7
BBB_2 -> 5
}
```

Which produces the output:

[image: result image]

The red nodes are not horizontally centered in their cluster.

It would also need to work if `cluster_south_b` was updated to

```
    subgraph cluster_south_b {
        label="bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb"

        7 [ label="" fillcolor="red" ]
        8 [ label="" fillcolor="red" ]
        9 [ label="" fillcolor="red" ]
        10 [ label="" fillcolor="red" ]

        7 -> 8
        7 -> 9
        8 -> 9
        8 -> 10
        9 -> 10
    }
```

which produces the output of:

[image: result image]

What comes close is adding the graph attribute `nodesep=.75` just below `bgcolor="gray"` (that was suggested on the [Graphviz forum](https://forum.graphviz.org/t/how-can-i-center-nodes-in-a-graphviz-cluster/2020)). But manually fine-tuning that value is not a practical solution for me.

Is it possible to have them horizontally centered? If so, how?

Comment: Do you also want AAA and BBB to aligned over the clusters?

Comment: I want the red circles to be horizontally centered in their group. Nothing else matters for this question.

Answer (score 1):

There is no guaranteed way to center a set of nodes within a larger (wider) cluster, but this seems to work pretty well

- put the nodes in a separate, embedded cluster - now somewhat disconnected from the wide label
- use **constraint=false** to help keep AAA and BBB from "pulling" the new clusters away from the center
- use **rank=source" to keep root at the top
- whoops, and use **peripheries=0** to visually hide the cluster box

```
        label=""
    peripheries=1
        7 [ label="" fillcolor="red" ]
        8 [ label="" fillcolor="red" ]

        7 -> 8
    }
    }

edge[constraint=false]
root -> AAA_1
root -> BBB_2
}
AAA_1 -> 7
BBB_2 -> 5
}
```

and

```
digraph G {
bgcolor="gray"

node [
style=filled
shape="circle"
fillcolor="green4"
penwidth="2"
color="green1"
fontcolor="white"
]

{
rank=source
root [
   shape="box"
   color="white"
   fontcolor="white"
   label="hello"
]
}

subgraph clusterXXX{
peripheries=1
AAA_1 [
    label="AAA"
]

BBB_2 [
    label="BBB"
]

subgraph cluster_ccc {
    color=gray
    fillcolor="blue"
    style=filled
    label="ccccc"
    labelloc=b
    fontcolor="white"
    labeljust=l
peripheries=1

    subgraph cluster_south_a {
      label="aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"
      subgraph cluster_south_a1 {
        label="" peripheries=1
        5 [ label="" fillcolor="red" ]
        6 [ label="" fillcolor="red" ]

        5 -> 6
      }
    }


    subgraph cluster_south_b {
      label="bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb"
      subgraph cluster_south_b1 {
        label="" peripheries=1
        7 [ label="" fillcolor="red" ]
        8 [ label="" fillcolor="red" ]
        9 [ label="" fillcolor="red" ]
        10 [ label="" fillcolor="red" ]

        7 -> 8
        7 -> 8
        7 -> 9
        8 -> 9
        8 -> 10
        9 -> 10
      }
    }
  }
}

{
edge [constraint=false]
root -> AAA_1
root -> BBB_2
}
AAA_1 -> 7
BBB_2 -> 5
}
```

Giving:
[image]

and
[image]

Comment: It works well for this case, but as noted, there is no generic solution, which is what I need. I am hopeful that there will be at some point.

Comment: You can create a generic solution (centering the inner cluster in the outer cluster that contains the label) using the Graphviz **gvpr** (https://www.graphviz.org/pdf/gvpr.1.pdf) post-processor, but it would be a bit of work